# UIButton and UIControlStateHighlighted issues when starting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard, uicontrol

for my UIButton I have its Default State Config set to buttonLong_beige.png and Highlighted State Config set to buttonLong_beige_pressed.png everything works as it should when the button is pressed, I press the button and the image changes from buttonLong_beige.png to buttonLong_beige_pressed.png each time i press it but the issue is when the app starts... before the button is even selected, it is already highlighted even though I never touched it yet... but once I press the button it returns to buttonLong_beige.png and then changes back and forth each time its pressed..... I have no code to display since this is all done in the storyboard, im very confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this in the "atribute inspector"

[image: This is how it should looks]

Its looks thats your button starts highligted, so un-check that.